# tcsh: var with current command

Tags: tcsh

in tcsh !$ is the last argument of the last command line:

```
m:~> man find
m:~> echo !$
find
```

I'm searching a way to get the current command line (before entered)

```
m:~> echo $current_comm
echo
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`!#` refers to the current command. It can be indexed by appending a `:` and a number.

For example:

```
% echo !#:0
echo echo
echo
%
```

(The shell prints history expansions before executing them, which is why the `echo echo` line appears.)

A more elaborate example:

```
% echo arg1 arg2 arg3 COMMAND=!#:0 ARG1=!#:1 ARG2=!#:2 ARG3=!#:3
echo arg1 arg2 arg3 COMMAND=echo ARG1=arg1 ARG2=arg2 ARG3=arg3
arg1 arg2 arg3 COMMAND=echo ARG1=arg1 ARG2=arg2 ARG3=arg3
%
```

For more information, `man tcsh` and search for "History substitution".